# new ModelAndView not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to run a springMVC application but its showing blank page to me.

In my controller class I have

```
@Controller
public class LoginController extends CommonController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
        public ModelAndView login(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
         logger.info("something"); // printing something in logs
         return new ModelAndView("login");//But failing here not loading login.jsp
    }
}
```

Its coming inside login method as if I print something before return its printing but failing at return statement and i am not getting any exception

Inside my spring-servlet.xml. I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jemmmedia.organise" />

    <!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

--------
-------

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"
       p:prefixJson="true" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

and my login.jsp is at /core/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp

and  inside pom.xml I have

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>mvnproject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

      <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config> 

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error404</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error403</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/exception</location>
    </error-page>
```

My logs are aready set to Debug level and it seems there is no error and some of last files from logs are

```
'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
[ INFO] 2014-04-16 21:53:53 Mapped URL path [/files/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1'
[ INFO] 2014-04-16 21:53:53 Mapped URL path [/profileImages/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2'
[ INFO] 2014-04-16 21:53:53 Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
[ INFO] 2014-04-16 21:53:53 Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#1'
[ INFO] 2014-04-16 21:53:53 Starting beans in phase 2147483647
[ INFO] 2014-04-16 21:53:53 Starting Quartz Scheduler now
[ INFO] 2014-04-16 21:53:53 FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 670 ms
```

Comment: If you have logging configured, turn it to debug level and post it here. Also lets see whats there in your web.xml

Comment: Hi Prasad, I have added my web.xml and my logs. please let me know if you need more information

Comment: The JSP itself might be useful. Plus the directory structure under `WEB-INF/jsp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some issues at work; now I was able in checking your code; here my steps:

- I downloaed the github source code
- I executed a mvn clean install on order to download all the needed libraries

Now all the libraries have been downloaded and I started in checked the issue. First of all in the main pom I had to add the following dependendcies:

```
<!--Angelo-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>  
<!--Fine Angelo-->
```

By adding these dependencies, everything compiled just fine. But issues didn't finish here; infact in the iBatis mapper file you had a lot of wrong class names. I guess that you (or somebody else) did a refactoryng of the model classes and forgot to update the mapper files (and I'm wondering how this code could run on your tomcat)

So I modified all the XML files and I tried to launche the application; I had to modify also the spring-security.xml file by adding this intestation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

Once I did this I run again the server and the application started with no error; when I typed the url for the login page, the `com.jemmmedia.organise.service.impl.controller.LoginController.login(HttpSession, HttpServletResponse, HttpServletRequest, Model, FeedEntryBean, int, int, String)`has been successfully called; and as it happened to you the ModelAndView for login was null
This is the console output:

```
18:48:06,932 INFO  [LoginController] model View: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'login'; model is null
```

But, eve if the modelandview is null, the login page appears to me

So basically I strongly suggest to yuo to check the mappers files and the spring-security file

I hope this can help
Cheers,
Angelo

Comment: Thanks a lot Angelo.. I am very happy and very relieved for this.  I'll check this today evening. Up vote for this :). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it's returning results in JSON format; try to check with firebug the response; if the server response is in JSON format, this is related to the fact that you have 2 viewResolser; yuo should use a ContentNegotiationgViewResolver

Comment: Hi Angelo I have test it in both chrome and firefox it just displaying the blank page with head tag with style tag and body tag is empty and I tried with ContentNegotiationViewResolver and getting the exception "nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiationgViewResolver "

Comment: I removed MappingJacksonJsonView but still I am getting the same blank page

Comment: It does not make any difference even I comment both the view resolvers

Comment: From your log file fragment I see that the login url is not mapped...is the controller in a package that you scan (e.g. in com.jemmmedia.organise o any sub-package?

Comment: Hi Angelo, if it would not have scanning then it would not have print the logger info. Could it be any other reason also if there is sub-package ?

Comment: Hi Angelo, Could it be something with spring version 3.0.7 as previously it was working with spring 3.1.1. But as now I am converting the project into maven so there was some conflict with spring 3.1.1 and spring security so I have to downgrade my spring version

Comment: @user965884 pardon me....I'll give a look tomorrow and I'll let you know....in the meantime if you can create a project with the problem on Github it would be great

Comment: Its ok Angelo. Thank you very much I try to create the project on Github

Comment: Hi Angelo, have you got any chance to look into the code? Thanks

Comment: @user965884 sorry I had some troubles...I'm just giving a look....I'll be back to you in the next few hours :) pardon me again

Comment: Hi Angelo, did you get time to look into this? I still looking into that but don't know why its not working. I tried to print ModelAndView and getting this 'modelandview reference to view with name 'login': model is null'

Answer (score 0):

Why you need this below config?

> <bean
>   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"
>   p:prefixJson="true" />

I think it will work well when you remove above bean.